# How I can either deny a login or registration a user based on current session

Tags: python, html, django, redirect, view

How can I deny or redirect an active user to the logged-in screen?

I want, user only can access pages when current session allows the access.

Is this can be done directly in the HTML code or only in views ?

Comment: depends on the needs, but can be achived on both ways if just have login nav. header then it would be better to do in templates. But for any other I think in views would be better option. Just use if request.user.is_authenticated(): redirect(''your url')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you mean that the user shouldn't see the login and signup links (maybe in the topbar). This can be done in the template as:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<!-- show logout link/button -->
{% else %}
<!-- show login and signup links/buttons -->
{% endif %}
```

Also you should additionally take care of the login view in your python code for consistency (maybe security too?). I think you can do this (not tested):

```
def login(request):
    # check if it's a GET/POST method
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
      return redirect(reverse('your_homepage_for_example'))
    # do login
```

Comment: That code is correct, only with a slight variation could it operates , thank you very much !